# Ошибка при билде многомодульность

Tags: java, android, kotlin, модули

Есть главный модуль и второй (Phone and Tables Module)

код первого (главного)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.unique.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
....

 implementation project(":network")
.....
```

второго

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.io.network"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
...
```

при билде появляется ошибка
Dependent features configured but no package ID was set.
Почему?? не могу никак понять.

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант попробовать сделать так в build.gradle вашего базового модуля:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    application project(":firstName")
    feature project(":secondName") // кажется тут у вас feature project(":network")
}
```

Второй вариант это во втором модуле заменить/добавить

```
// Все три варианта попробуйте во втором модуле
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Совместите все вариации первого и второго варианта вместе или добавьте больше информации

Answer (score 0):

Второй модуль использует плагин id 'kotlin-parcelize'. Поэтому его надо добавить и в главный модуль.